# Default arguments in ruby

Tags: ruby

I am trying to set up default parameter and I would like to skip passing an argument and assign particular arguments in the function call. But, I am not able to get the desired output.

```
require "json"
def stun(voltage = 0,frequency = 0,range = "",scope = "")
    body = {
        :voltage => voltage,
        :frequency => frequency,
        :range => range,
        :scope => scope
    }
    response = body.to_json
end


stun(voltage = 1,frequency = 2,scope = "universal")
```

As you can see in the code above, I am trying to assign value to scope while keeping the range parameter an empty string. I am getting the following response.

```
"{\"voltage\":1,\"frequency\":2,\"range\":\"universal\",\"scope\":\"\"}"
```

My desired output would be to have range as an empty string and scope as "universal"

Comment: Isn’t working because the last param you passed it’s range, not scope. You can achieve this by passing a hash instead

Comment: Yes, I want to skip passing range and directly pass the scope.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You've set up default values for the arguments, but you're still using positional arguments, the first argument will always go to `voltage`, the second to `frequency`, the third to `range`, the fourth to `scope`. Since you are passing 3 arguments, you end up passing `voltage`, `frequency`, and `range`.

Those equal signs in the method call, aren't doing what you think. Instead of telling ruby which parameter is getting assigned, you are creating a local variable with those names:

```
stun(voltage = 1,frequency = 2,scope = "universal")
puts [voltage, frequency, scope].inspect # => [1, 2, "universal"]
```

Ruby does have a way, with named parameters, to do what you want though:

```
def stun(voltage: 0, frequency: 0, range: "", scope: "")
    body = {
        :voltage => voltage,
        :frequency => frequency,
        :range => range,
        :scope => scope
    }

    response = body.to_json
end

puts stun(voltage: 1, frequency: 2, scope: "universal")
# => {"voltage":1,"frequency":2,"range":"","scope":"universal"}
```

This is available (I believe) since Ruby 2.0. If you use these though, you'll always need to pass the parameters with their names, for instance:

```
stun(1, 2, "", "universal")
```

raises `wrong number of arguments (given 4, expected 0)` now. This isn't a bad thing, in my opinion, just something to keep in mind.

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered passing a hash?

```
def stun(params)
    body = {
        voltage: 0,
        frequency: 2,
        range: '',
        scope: ''
    }
    body.merge!(params)
    response = body.to_json
end

stun({voltate: 1, frequency: 2, scope: 'universal'})
=> "{\"voltage\":0,\"frequency\":2,\"range\":\"\",\"scope\":\"universal\",\"voltate\":1}"
```